# Springboot Version upgrade from 2.1.6 to 2.2.1 and spring-cloud issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, spring-webflux

TIA

I am trying to upgrade Springboot application from **2.1.6** to **2.2.1** including spring cloud version from **Greenwich.SR2** to **Hoxton.SR5**

Application not started

The following method did not exist:
org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.client.ReactorNettyWebSocketClient.setHandlePing(Z)V

The method's class, org.springframework.web.reactive.socket.client.ReactorNettyWebSocketClient is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/c:/.m2/5.2.1.Release/spring-webflux-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar!/ReactorNettyWebSocketClient.class

it was loaded from the following location:
file:/c:/.m2/5.2.1.Release/spring-webflux-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar

What exactly I need to do to resolve the above issue.

Comment: Upgrade to boot 2.2.7?

Comment: or maybe actually post your pom.xml so we dont have to guess your dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade your springboot version to 2.2.7.RELEASE on your gradle.build, we had the same problem and with this version fixed!